# c# Form with custom design code doesn't show up

Tags: c#, winforms, show

I am currently working on a project that allows the user to design his own WinForm (using DesignSurface). Therefore I wrote an algrotithm to create Designer-Code for the form. Everything works fine, except for one thing: The form, once compiled, won't show up. Everything should be working; I could not figure out what the problem was. Anyways, here's the code:

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    public mainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
    private CustomButton button1;
    private CustomTextBox textBox3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private CustomTextBox textBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private CustomTextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1; 
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.checkBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.checkBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.button1 = new CustomButton();
        this.textBox3 = new CustomTextBox();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox2 = new CustomTextBox();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox1 = new CustomTextBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        //
        //checkBox3
        //
        this.checkBox3.AutoCheck = false;
        this.checkBox3.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBox3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(-986896);
        this.checkBox3.Text = @"";
        this.checkBox3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.checkBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(187, 151);
        this.checkBox3.Name = @"checkBox3";
        this.checkBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(87, 17);
        this.checkBox3.TabIndex = 9;
        this.checkBox3.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //checkBox2
        //
        this.checkBox2.AutoCheck = false;
        this.checkBox2.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(-986896);
        this.checkBox2.Text = @"";
        this.checkBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.checkBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 151);
        this.checkBox2.Name = @"checkBox2";
        this.checkBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 17);
        this.checkBox2.TabIndex = 8;
        this.checkBox2.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //checkBox1
        //
        this.checkBox1.AutoCheck = false;
        this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(-986896);
        this.checkBox1.Text = @"";
        this.checkBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 151);
        this.checkBox1.Name = @"checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 17);
        this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 7;
        this.checkBox1.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //button1
        //
        this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(-986896);
        this.button1.Text = @"";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this.button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 187);
        this.button1.Name = @"button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(309, 38);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 6;
        this.button1.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //textBox3
        //
        this.textBox3.UseForCustoming = true;
        this.textBox3.CustomingName = @"";
        this.textBox3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("White");
        this.textBox3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 116);
        this.textBox3.Name = @"textBox3";
        this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(306, 20);
        this.textBox3.TabIndex = 5;
        this.textBox3.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //label3
        //
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Text = @"";
        this.label3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(-986896);
        this.label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 100);
        this.label3.Name = @"label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 13);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label3.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //textBox2
        //
        this.textBox2.UseForCustoming = true;
        this.textBox2.CustomingName = @"";
        this.textBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("White");
        this.textBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 71);
        this.textBox2.Name = @"textBox2";
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(306, 20);
        this.textBox2.TabIndex = 3;
        this.textBox2.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //label2
        //
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Text = @"";
        this.label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(-986896);
        this.label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 55);
        this.label2.Name = @"label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(82, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label2.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //textBox1
        //
        this.textBox1.UseForCustoming = true;
        this.textBox1.CustomingName = @"";
        this.textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("White");
        this.textBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 25);
        this.textBox1.Name = @"textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(306, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.textBox1.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //label1
        //
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Text = @"";
        this.label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(-986896);
        this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 9);
        this.label1.Name = @"label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(51, 13);
        this.label1.Tag = @"XC";
        //
        //mainForm
        //
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(455, 275);
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(-986896);
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(349, 276);
        this.Text = @"";
        this.TopLevel = false;
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");
        this.Name = @"opForm";
        this.Tag = @"";
        this.Controls.Add(checkBox3);
        this.Controls.Add(checkBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(checkBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(button1);
        this.Controls.Add(textBox3);
        this.Controls.Add(label3);
        this.Controls.Add(textBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(label2);
        this.Controls.Add(textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(label1);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
    }
}
```

And here's the code that creates the form:

```
static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new mainForm());
        }
    }
```

I don't get what's wrong with this code. Maybe someone can help me out here.
Chester

Comment: Who creates the instance of the new form and runs it? I am new to DesignSurface.

Comment: This is the application the main application generates, it has nothing to do with DesignSurface. The main Thread creates the instance, and runs it using Application.Run(new mainForm()).

Comment: i am not sure but i don't see a Form.Show() anywhere maybe that is what you are missing.

Comment: You are right - there's no Form.Show(). But it is not needed in this case. Application.Run(Form) does this for me. Adding this.Show() or Form.Show() does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing I think the values for ClientSize and Size are clashing. Actually I believe only one should be set and the last one to be set will win.

But the one line that prevents the window from showing up is this:

```
this.TopLevel = false;
```

Leave it out or set it to `true` (the default) and your window will show just fine..

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A top-level form is a window that has no parent form, or whose parent
>   form is the desktop window. Top-level windows are typically used as
>   the main form in an application.

So if `DesignSurface` has set it to `false` you probably have told it that you are creating something else than a main form.. I believe `MDI` child windows have it set to `false`, but I'm not sure, `MDI` is soo long away..

Comment: And yes, it was set to false because of the DesignSurface.